# How can I make HoneySQL handle order by as a compound key?

Tags: clojure, honeysql

Note that the output has been "stylized" so it reads better here on SO.

What I've got...

```
(sql/format 
  (-> 
    (sqlh/select :*) 
    (sqlh/from :event) 
    (sqlh/merge-where [:in :field_id ["1673576", "1945627", "1338971"]]) 
    (sqlh/merge-where [:in :layer ["fha.abs" "fha.rank" "fha.true-color"]])
    (sqlh/merge-order-by :field_id)
    (sqlh/merge-order-by :layer)
    (sqlh/merge-order-by :event_date)
    (sqlh/limit 5)))
=>
["SELECT * 
  FROM event 
  WHERE ((field_id in (?, ?, ?)) AND (layer in (?, ?, ?))) 
  ORDER BY field_id, layer, event_date 
  LIMIT ?"
 "1673576"
 "1945627"
 "1338971"
 "fha.abs"
 "fha.rank"
 "fha.true-color"
 5]
```

What I want...

```
(sql/format 
  (-> 
    (sqlh/select :*) 
    (sqlh/from :event) 
    (sqlh/merge-where [:in :field_id ["1673576", "1945627", "1338971"]]) 
    (sqlh/merge-where [:in :layer ["fha.abs" "fha.rank" "fha.true-color"]])
    ;;; this doesn't work, but is conceptually what I'm looking for
    (sqlh/merge-order-by [:field_id :layer :event_date])
    (sqlh/limit 5)))
=>
["SELECT * 
  FROM event 
  WHERE ((field_id in (?, ?, ?)) AND (layer in (?, ?, ?))) 
  ORDER BY (field_id, layer, event_date) 
  LIMIT ?"
 "1673576"
 "1945627"
 "1338971"
 "fha.abs"
 "fha.rank"
 "fha.true-color"
 5]
```

How can I get HoneySQL to emit SQL that treats my order by clause as the compound key that the table itself is using as the Primary Key?

It seems HoneySQL should be able to do this as it "does the right thing" when presented the same challenge in a where clause like...

```
(sql/format
  (->
    (sqlh/select :*)
    (sqlh/from :event)
    (sqlh/merge-where [:= [:field_id :layer :event_date] ["1338971" "fha.abs" (c/from-string "2011-08-02T10:54:55-07")]])))
=>
["SELECT * FROM event WHERE (field_id, layer, event_date) = (?, ?, ?)"
 "1338971"
 "fha.abs"
 #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0xe59f807 "2011-08-02T17:54:55.000Z"]]
```

Comment: how is the second generated query different from first one ?

Comment: @AshishNegi In the 2nd query the order by clause is on a tuple rather than 3 individual fields.  Ultimately this will allow me to reverse the sort order in a single statement.

Comment: yes but does not both give same result ?.. whether you have tuple or individual fields.

Comment: @AshishNegi  It gives the same initial result, that is correct, but when I look forward into what I am trying to do with this; implement a paging solution that requires only LIMIT and not OFFSET, I need to be able to treat these 3 distinct fields as a unit.  HoneySQL does the correct thing with this in a where clause (I added this to the question), I am seeking the equivalent behavior in the order-by.

Comment: May be you should try putting real question about limit/offset and how with order by they are giving different results with/without tuple..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to look at the format behavior on `order-by`

```
(sql/format {:order-by [:c1 :c2]}) 
=> ["ORDER BY c1, c2"]
(sql/format {:order-by [[:c1 :desc] :c2]})
=> ["ORDER BY c1 DESC, c2"]
```

that is the struct about order-by which will be generated.

If you look at the macro `defhelper`  it will do two things.

1. defrecord for the spec type
2. define a function to call the mutimethod

`(do
  (defmethod
    build-clause
    :order-by
    [_ m fields]
    (assoc m :order-by (collify fields)))
  (defn order-by [& args__14903__auto__]
    (let [[m__14904__auto__ args__14903__auto__] (if
                                                   (plain-map?
                                                     (first
                                                       args__14903__auto__))
                                                   [(first
                                                      args__14903__auto__)
                                                    (rest
                                                      args__14903__auto__)]
                                                   [{}
                                                    args__14903__auto__])]
      (build-clause :order-by m__14904__auto__ args__14903__auto__)))
  (alter-meta! #'order-by assoc :arglists '([fields] [m fields])))`

The `collify` is very simple.

```
 (defn collify [x]
     (if (coll? x) x [x]))
```

So , we need to look at `defn order-by`  function . 
When you call `(sqlh/merge-order-by {} [:a :b])`,

`args__14903__auto__ = '({} [:a :b])`

The first `if` will create two var `m__14904__auto__ = {}` and `args__14903__auto__ = (rest args__14903__auto__) = ([:a :b])`.

So, I guess the merge-order-by function is wrong.

I solve your problem like this.

```
(sql/format
  (->
    (sqlh/select :*)
    (sqlh/from :event)
    (sqlh/merge-where [:in :field_id ["1673576", "1945627", "1338971"]])
    (sqlh/merge-where [:in :layer ["fha.abs" "fha.rank" "fha.true-color"]])
    (sqlh/merge-order-by [:field_id :desc] :layer :event_date)
    (sqlh/limit 5)))
```

Comment: Not quite, but good effort.  The more I stare at this, the more I think that HoneySQL helpers aren't capable of doing this but maybe it doesn't matter.  When I look at PostgreSQL's EXPLAIN of the actual query, it has no issue with ORDER BY (field_id, layer, event_date) DESC, vs (ORDER BY field_id DESC, layer DESC, event_date DESC); it seems to produce the same query plan...it just bugs me that I have to do this so fine-grained because the helper class doesn't really map directly to the underlying SQL

Answer (score 1):

Its been over 2 years, but I finally know enough Clojure and have worked with HoneySQL long enough to see what my younger self was missing.  It didn't want the compound key as a vector:  `sqlh/order-by` is variadic:

```
(doc sqlh/order-by)
-------------------------
honeysql.helpers/order-by
([& fields] [m & fields])
  nil
```

What it really wanted was `(sqlh/order-by :field_id :layer [:event_date :desc])`.  The vector was only needed to make a specific field sort DESC.

So this was what I was trying to do:

```
(-> (sqlh/select :*)
    (sqlh/from :event)
    (sqlh/merge-where [:in :field_id field-ids])
    (sqlh/merge-where (cond (not-empty layers) [:in :layer layers]))
    (sqlh/merge-where (make-where-for-timestamp
                        :event_date event-date-from event-date-to))
    (sqlh/merge-where (make-where-for-timestamp
                        :updated_at updated-at-from updated-at-to))
    (sqlh/order-by :field_id :layer [:event_date :desc])
    sql/format)
=>
["SELECT * FROM event WHERE ((field_id in (?)) AND (layer in (?, ?, ?))) ORDER BY field_id, layer, event_date DESC"
 "1325629"
 "fha.true-color"
 "fha.abs"
 "fha.rank"]
```

@savior was correct at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356529/688355 all along.  My Clojure wasn't good enough to understand it.